# Редирект на страницу через php

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Как сделать так, чтобы при редиректе через header() текущее положение на странице оставалось на своем месте и не перекидывало на верх страницы?

Comment: текущее никак вроде, только по хэшам, что-то вроде header("Location: /page/#something");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно инкапсулировать JS который мотает на определённое место. А дальше уже  привязываться к какому-то элементу. Ну либо перед редиректом пробрасывать позицию скролла. Хотя для разных страниц высота может быть разной а значит и скролл может не попасть.

```
/page?pos=1443

document.getScroll= function(){
 if (window.pageYOffset!= undefined) {
   return [pageXOffset, pageYOffset];
 } else {
   var sx, sy, d= document, r= d.documentElement, b= d.body;
   sx= r.scrollLeft || b.scrollLeft || 0;
   sy= r.scrollTop || b.scrollTop || 0;

   return [sx, sy];
 }
};
document.getScroll();

window.scrollTo(0, 1443);
```

Промотать до нужного элемента можно так

```
/page?elm=answer-836245

document.getElementById('answer-836245').scrollIntoView();
```

P.S. Но что-то мне подсказывает что вы не тем занимаетесь